# When I use MSBuild to build an Android Makefile project and print log, I can't put string "error" and ":" together

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, makefile, msbuild, nmake

I wrote a script to build an [Android NDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_software_development#Android_NDK) application, and the source is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LOG_ID_RADIO 1
#define ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG 3
#define LOG_TAG "TEST_LOG"

#define LOGD(...) printf(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,LOG_TAG ,VA_ARGS);

int main()
{
    size_t datalen = 0;
    LOGD("data length error: %d", datalen);  <-- Please notice the string: "error:"
    return 0;
}
```

The script is below:

```
cd C:/workspace/ndkTest/ndk-build/TestCC/jni
echo ====
call ndk-build  -C C:/workspace/ndkTest/ndk-build/TestCC/jni -B
set path=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r15c;%path%
echo error=%ERRORLEVEL%
pause
```

#### Reproduce steps:

1. Download the project: [testcc.zip](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/storage/attachments/23922-testcc.zip), extract this `.zip` file, remember the `build.bat` location, for example: my `build.bat` [location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd1Hp.png).
2. Open the `build.bat` file, maybe you need change two things:

   - `C:/workspace/ndkTest/ndk-build/TestCC/jni`               <-- build.bat location
   - `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r15c`  <-- NDK Location
3. In Visual Studio, create an [Android Makefile Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjwVP.png), right click this project and select *Properties*, the [default setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaQHX.png), find *NMake* → *General* → *Build Command Line*, change it to your `build.bat` location, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiWyi.png).
4. Build this solution.

When I use the string `error:`,

```
LOGD("data length error: %d", datalen);
```

this project will result in *build failed*. Error log:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Project14, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>====
1>make: Entering directory `C:/workspace/ndkTest/ndk-build/TestCC/jni'
1>[arm64-v8a] Compile        : testtime <= timetest.c
1>C:/workspace/ndkTest/ndk-build/TestCC/jni/./timetest.c(16,2): warning G5552ABC2: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type 'const char *' [-Wint-conversion]
1>EXEC : LOGD("data length error : %d", datalen);
1>        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1>C:/workspace/ndkTest/ndk-build/TestCC/jni/./timetest.c:10:26: note: expanded from macro 'LOGD'
1>#define LOGD(...) printf(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,LOG_TAG ,__VA_ARGS__);
1>                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1>C:/workspace/ndkTest/ndk-build/TestCC/jni/./timetest.c:7:27: note: expanded from macro 'ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG'
1>#define ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG 3
1>                          ^
1>C:/Users/v-shenya/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../sysroot/usr/include\stdio.h:129:24: note: passing argument to parameter '__fmt' here
1>int printf(const char* __fmt, ...) __printflike(1, 2);
1>                       ^
1>1 warning generated.
1>[arm64-v8a] Executable     : testtime
1>[arm64-v8a] Install        : testtime => libs/arm64-v8a/testtime
1>make: Leaving directory `C:/workspace/ndkTest/ndk-build/TestCC/jni'
1>error=0
1>Press any key to continue . . .
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(44,5): error MSB3073: The command "C:\workspace\ndkTest\ndk-build\TestCC\jni\build.bat" exited with code -1.
1>Done building project "Project14.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

But when I change `error:` to `error` (trailing space) or `errdor:`, it just doesn't put "error" and ":" together:

```
LOGD("data length errdor: %d", datalen);  or
LOGD("data length error  %d", datalen);
```

This project will build with success:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Project14, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>====
1>make: Entering directory `C:/workspace/ndkTest/ndk-build/TestCC/jni'
1>[arm64-v8a] Compile        : testtime <= timetest.c
1>C:/workspace/ndkTest/ndk-build/TestCC/jni/./timetest.c(16,2): warning G5552ABC2: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type 'const char *' [-Wint-conversion]
1>        LOGD("data length error %d", datalen);
1>        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1>C:/workspace/ndkTest/ndk-build/TestCC/jni/./timetest.c:10:26: note: expanded from macro 'LOGD'
1>#define LOGD(...) printf(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,LOG_TAG ,__VA_ARGS__);
1>                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1>C:/workspace/ndkTest/ndk-build/TestCC/jni/./timetest.c:7:27: note: expanded from macro 'ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG'
1>#define ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG 3
1>                          ^
1>C:/Users/v-shenya/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../sysroot/usr/include\stdio.h:129:24: note: passing argument to parameter '__fmt' here
1>int printf(const char* __fmt, ...) __printflike(1, 2);
1>                       ^
1>1 warning generated.
1>[arm64-v8a] Executable     : testtime
1>[arm64-v8a] Install        : testtime => libs/arm64-v8a/testtime
1>make: Leaving directory `C:/workspace/ndkTest/ndk-build/TestCC/jni'
1>error=0
1>Press any key to continue . . .
1>Done building project "Project14.vcxproj".
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

My Visual Studio 2017 version is 15.6.6. Is this a bug of MSBuild? How can I fix this?

My project is very huge, and changing the string `error:` was not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

MSBuild parses the output of any command it executes for standardized error or warning messages. Having `error :` in the output of your `bat` will be detected by MSBuild as an actual error message and cause the build to be marked as failure.

You can see the error detection code of MSBuild [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/src/Shared/CanonicalError.cs) and [a blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msbuild/2006/11/02/msbuild-visual-studio-aware-error-messages-and-message-formats/) from 2006 that describes this feature.

Now you have several options to solve this:

1. Change your project to use the `Exec` command to run the bat with the `IgnoreStandardErrorWarningFormat` property:

   ```
   <Exec Command="path/to/your/batfile.bat" IgnoreStandardErrorWarningFormat="true"></Exec>
   ```
2. Change the text in your code:

   ```
   LOGD("invalid data length: %d", datalen);
   ```
3. Fix the compiler warning that causes that line to be printed out in the first place.